# Automatic GCM registration?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to register to GCM service automatically (programatically) in order to get the sender ID (or whichever id is required)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. The registration to GCM service is always done programatically in an Android application. You send a registration request that contains the sender Id (which is a Google Project Id) and you get in the reply a Registration Id, which you send to your server (which uses that Id to send notifications to your Application on a specific device).

Unless you mean getting the Project Id itself programatically. I don't think that's possible. You have to create a Google API project manually in order to get such Id. You can, however, write code in your Android application that would connect your server to get the Project Id (which you already created manually), and then use it to register to GCM. This would allow you to change the Project Id your application is registered to without updating your application's code.